# Omniauth authentication - catch the moment when the user gets redirected to google

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth

```
# Gemfile
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'devise'

# view
- if user_signed_in?
  Signed in as 
  = current_user.oauth_name
  = button_to('Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete)
- else
  = link_to('Sign in with Google', user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2))
```

What's the best way to catch the moment when the user gets redirected to google for authentication?

It could be by "javascript onclick", but I want to catch the moment on the server somehow (if it's possible) because I need to save some variable to the session.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of init [callbacks](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/da86405a781630af172dadbe67796ec88d6c4973/lib/omniauth/builder.rb) that can be used. I guess you need OmniAuth.config.before_request_phase

```
#config/initializers/omniauth.rb
OmniAuth.config.before_request_phase do |env|
  env['omniauth.auth']
  # Your code there
end
```

Comment: but I can't access "params" from there, can I?

Comment: see  updates, you have access to rack environment and i think you can get omniauth.auth params and others. I do not know  how to get params, but you can inspect env object and see what you need.